# Accessing custom URL parameters

Tags: query-string

I have created a page in wordpress to accept query string parameters. For the wordpress to recognize the query string parameters, URL parameter is added to query_vars using the following code snippet in Theme functions (functions.php) file. Below is the code snippet I have added to recognize the URL parameter 'website':

```
function add_query_vars( $aVars )
{
    $aVars[] = "website";
    return $aVars;
}
// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

When I access the page using the URL http://example.com/custompage/?website=google, the URL parameter value is blank. Below is the code to access the query string value in page and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['website'])) {
    $siteName = $wp_query->query_vars['website'];
    echo $siteName;
}
```

Please let me know what could be wrong in the above approach to access the URL parameter value in the wordpress page.

Comment: your code works as-is for me

Comment: Is `$wp_query` the object of global WP_Query class? Or custom?

Answer (score 1):

Global declaration for the variable was missing in the page. After adding the following declaration, code works as expected.

```
global $wp_query;
```